# Props with styles not applying until I change file (Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({   
    switchBase: (props) => {
      return {
        "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
          //@ts-ignore
          color: props.inputBoxColor,
        },
        "& .Mui-checked": {
          //@ts-ignore
          color: "props.inputBoxColorFocused,
        },
        "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
          //@ts-ignore
          backgroundColor: props.inputBoxColorFocused,
        },
      };
    },
  })
);
```

The user can change the color and it gets updated in state. I passed it in here. It dosent work until I change something in the file. But when I refresh again it dosent get applied. My guess is that the props are not intiallized yet. But it still dosent work when the state gets changed. Only when the file is changed.